# Passing JSON value from Spreadsheet in Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to pass the value to a JSON from the google spreadsheet. But I am getting a invalid json string error. Can you please help me out where I am doing wrong?

Please find the code snippet below

Code:

```
for(var i=0;i>=10;i++)
 {
 var userEmail = sheet.getRange(3, 2, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
 var owner = {
 email: userEmail[i],
 role: 'OWNER'
 };
 owner = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(owner, groupEmail);
 Logger.log('User %s added as a owner of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
 Browser.msgBox("Owner Successfully Added!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var userEmail must be outside the for() loop and you must also select first value of the object userEmail[i].
In your code I also assume sheet var is defined somewhere before this piece of code.

```
var userEmail = sheet.getRange(3, 2, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
for(var i in userEmail) {
 var owner = {
 email: userEmail[i][0],
 role: 'OWNER'
 };
 owner = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(owner, groupEmail);
 Logger.log('User %s added as a owner of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
 Browser.msgBox("Owner Successfully Added!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var userEmail = sheet.getRange(3, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues();
for(var i=0;i < userEmail.length; i++)
{
  var owner = {
    email: userEmail[i][0],
    role: 'OWNER'
  };
  owner = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(owner, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a owner of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
  Browser.msgBox("Owner Successfully Added!");
}
```

The third argument to `getRange` is the number of rows to read and since you start at row 3 - leaving out the first two rows - there are 2 less rows to read.
Also `getValues` returns a two dimensional array.